# How can I tell another script to instantiate a special prefab in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code that generate order of obstacles:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GroundSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public GameObject groundTile;
    public static string item;

    private List<string> listOfChoices = new List<string>{"box", "antitank", "barricade", "wheels"};
    private List<string> roadList = new List<string>();

    Vector3 nextSpawnPoint;

    void Start()
    {
        roadList = GenItemList(10, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < roadList.Count; i++)
        {
            item = roadList[i];
            GameObject temp = Instantiate(groundTile, nextSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
            nextSpawnPoint = temp.transform.GetChild(1).transform.position;
        }
    }

    public List<string> GenItemList(int numOfItems, int numOfTanks)
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, listOfChoices.Count);
            string add = listOfChoices[randomIndex];
            returnList.Add(add);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfTanks; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(1, numOfItems);
            returnList[randomIndex] = "tank";
            int tankIndex = randomIndex;

            int numOfMolotoves = Random.Range(1, 4);
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfMolotoves; j++)
            {
                randomIndex = Random.Range(0, (tankIndex - 1));
                if(returnList[randomIndex] != "molotov")
                {
                    returnList[randomIndex] = "molotov";
                }
                else
                {
                    numOfMolotoves++;
                }
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }

}
```

In the `void Start()` there is line:

```
item = roadList[i];
```

This line is an obstacle that I want to spawn (box, barricade, wheels, antitank or molotov).

I have `GroundTile` that has `GroundTileScript`. I instantiate `GroundTile`, but how do I tell to the current `GroundTile` to instantiate `item` from `GroundScript`? Is it actually possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming you have a `GroundTileScript` in the `GroundTile`object, you can do this.

```
GameObject tile = Instantiate(tileprefab);
tile.GetComponent<GroundTileScript>().Spawnitem;
```

I might be wrong, so tell me if something goes wrong.

Comment: Good answer, but I found another way. I just spawn obstacle by GroundSpawner on the GroundTile position

Answer (score 1):

You already saving groundTile gameObject data at variable temp.

```
GameObject temp = Instantiate(groundTile, nextSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identy);
```

All you gonna do is get component from `temp` gameObject what you spawned `GameObject temp` like below.

```
GroundTile tile = temp.GetComponent<GroundTile>();
```

And then you can use your public methods or get public variable value.

```
tile.DoSomeThing();
tile.somePublicVariable = 0;
```